# Is this an example of a zero-knowledge proof?

Tags: theory, zero-knowledge-proofs

I want to prove to a verifier that I know the passcode of a system. The system contains data/information of the verifier of which is only contained with this system. Since I know the passcode to the system, I retrieve data relating to the verifier and tell the verifier of this information. He acknowledge the information but not certain I know the passcode to the system since I could have randomly guessed this information. On the second instance, I reveal to him another piece of data relating pertaining to the verifier, he is a little bit more confident that I know the passcode.

Comment: `[He acknowledges]` reception, or match?

Comment: @Anon, do you know the meaning of "zero-knoweledge"?